# What is the effect of Google new algorithm for health related websites on ranking?

Tags: seo, migration, google-algorithm

My client has a dental services website and they did a website migration recently. They have lost ranking from 1st to lost for so many keywords. Now the web agency mentions the new google algorithm for health related websites as the main reason for drop in ranking.
But I found lots of mistakes in the migration process as well. Are they right or it can be because of some mistakes they made?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is too broad and opinionated because Google has not and will not disclose full details of the update. There is little to be said on the subject without speculation which leads to discussions rather than answers.

Comment: I recommend you research "Your money or your life (YMYL)" SEO.